# Changing variable set by parent class without modifying the constructor

Tags: php, oop

I have been searching for this since a couple of days but found no solution.

Here's my code:

```
// Main class
class My_Parent {

    private $foo = '';

    // The constructor is set. Now all extended classes will get it.
    function __construct() {
        var_dump( $foo );
    }

    function set_val( $value ) {
        $this->foo = $value;
    }

}

// Extended class
class My_Child extends My_Parent {

    // Here's the problem. I've modified the constructor
    function __construct() {
        parent::set_val( 'bar' );
        parent::__construct(); // I don't want to call the parent costructor again
    }

}

new My_Child();
```

This just work fine but not as I expect. I don't want to modify the constructor so I need to call it again from the parent. Which looks weird. I'm going to make an extendable framework for my projects. So, this thing is annoying.

I do want something like this:

```
class My_Child extends My_Parent {

    // Just set the value somehow. do not modify the constructor
    $this::set_val( 'bar' );

}

new My_Child();
```

So that, I don't have to call the constructor again. But the code above throws a syntax error.

Any hope about this?

Answer (score 0):

Just found a tricky solution.

First I've set up an empty function and called it in the constructor of parent class. Then I modified the variable through that function in extended class. The code looks like this:

```
// Main class
class My_Parent {

    private $foo = '';

    // The constructor is set. Now all extended classes will get it.
    function __construct() {

        // We open the portal so that the value can change
        $this->portal();

        // Then we use the value as we want
        var_dump( $foo );

    }

    function set_val( $value ) {
        $this->foo = $value;
    }

    // This function will play the role of constructor of extended classes
    function portal() {
    }

}

// Extended class
class My_Child extends My_Parent {

    // We just use portal to set the value. Constructor is still untouched!
    function portal() {
        parent::set_val( 'bar' );
    }

}

new My_Child();
```

This is working perfectly as I wanted. Everything is explained in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're over-thinking this. If you want to initialize the property with a constant value, you can simply declare it **protected** and override it in the subclass:

```
class MyParent {
    protected $foo = 'bar';

    // ...

    public function getFoo() {
        return $this->foo;
    }
}

class MyChild extends MyParent {
    protected $foo = 'baz';
}

echo (new MyParent())->getFoo(); // "bar"
echo (new MyChild())->getFoo(); // "baz"
```

Comment: Yes, that could do the job but I was trying to keep the variable private. As I mentioned in my question, it'm building a framework. So, I could go into some conflict if I declare my variables as protected.

Comment: @SohanZaman that's a valid argument in principle; however, in your answer you only shift the problem to another place. Instead of a protected variable that could be overwritten, you now have two (in your case even public!) functions that can be overwritten by child classes with a lot more side-effects.